# Ruby on Rails submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The submit_tag in Rails creates a submit button with various options. One of these is confirm, which allows you to specify a question string. When the user presses the button, a dialog pops up and displays the question and two buttons: OK to perform the submit, and Cancel to just close the dialog and not submit the form. That works fine except when the button is a cancel button. In this case, the question is, say, "Are you sure you want to cancel?", and the OK button means cancel, while the cancel button means to cancel the cancel. I mean it's functionally correct, but potentially confusing. Is there any way to rename the dialog buttons in this case? I'm using Rails 3.2.12.

Comment: Have you thought about using a dialog instead? From what I've read and done in the past, I've yet to find a way to change the values. With the dialog, you could have much more control.

Comment: Maybe so. By using a dialog, do you mean writing my own JavaScript function to display the dialog, and attaching it to the button via an "on submit" event, or something like that?

Comment: Yessir, that's what I mean. There may be a way to use confirm, but you can have it over and done with using dialog, then refactor later.